# Ruby simple way to list the next n numbers

Tags: ruby, jruby

In ruby we can easily generate 1 to n numbers by lots of ways, like

- `1.upto(10).to_a`
- `[*1..10]`

But I want to find out the next n numbers from the given number. For example, if the given number is 250, what's the simplest way to find the next 20 numbers (250..270)?

One way is:

```
n.upto(n+next),
```

So

```
250.upto(250+20) or [*250..(250+20)]
```

I just wanted to know if there is a default ruby method/way to handle this.

Answer (score 2):

You can also make use of lazy evaluation on ranges, and do something like

```
250.upto(1.0/0).take(20)
```

Comment: Ruby 1.9 also has `Float::INFINITY` which is more obvious than the division hack.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is something built-in in Ruby, but how to write your own method:

```
class Integer
  def next_with_step(step = nil)
    if step.is_a?(Fixnum)
      upto(self + step).to_a
    else
      next_without_step
    end
  end
  alias_method :next_without_step, :next
  alias_method :next, :next_with_step
end


1.next
=> 2
1.next(3).inspect
=> [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: A reopened-class monkeypatch and an alias that collides with a keyword? Ick.

Comment: First I don't understand people with arguments against monkey-patching. Please look at @dhh's presentation ["Why Ruby?"](http://david.heinemeierhansson.com/presentations), because monkey-patching is the best thing ever, and defines Ruby! And secondly, `next` is safe to use, it's already defined in the Intger class inside stdlib.

Comment: I heard dhh's presentation in person, and it did nothing to convince me that monkeypatching (or freedom-patching, or whatever) isn't used more often for evil than for good. For one-offs, for code that you don't intend to distribute, fine. For code that's supposed to be production-worthy, and especially code that you intend to be used by other people, reopened-class monkeypatching is irresponsible and lazy.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you could accomplish this:

```
n = 250
m = 5

puts (0...m).map{ |i| i + n }.inspect #=> [250, 251, 252, 253, 254]
```

Comment: Or: `puts (n-1...n+m).map(&:next)`.